# AWS application load balancer deassociate from waf

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, web-application-firewall

One Application load balancer is integrated with WAF web acl . And these webacl rule is managed by firewall manager from organisation account . Suddenly in the integration tab of ALB started showing that alb is no associated with WAF . Have any one faced these type of issue .

Checked in the cloudtrail logs and found that these are be removed by firewall manager .

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution .
Actually firewall manager is controlling the waf integration . The rule is like if associated accounts's loadbalancer have specific tag then integrate the alb with waf else not . So in my cases tags of the load balancer was wrong .